# gcse maths solving equations algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus

please can you help with this question
3(x+2)+5=2-x find what x is
I have expanded the brackets
3x+6+5=2-x
do I have to rearrange the equation after?

Comment: Yes, you should re-arrange it....

Comment: First , determine the sum $6+5$ ($11$) , then seperate the terms with and the terms without "$x$". Then, divide by the number appearing on the side with the "$x$"

Answer (score 0):

multiplying out we obtain
$$3x+6+5=2-x$$
simplifying
$$3x+11=2-x$$
adding $x$ on both sides
$$4x+11=2$$
substracting $11$
$$4x=-9$$
dividing by $4$ and we get $$x=-\frac{9}{4}$$